# Field Mapper could not be found, Consider defining a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

Customer service impl

```
package com.application.service.impl;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

@Autowired
private CustomerRepository custRepo;

@Autowired
private CustomerMapper mapper;

@Autowired
private HMergeMapper mergeMapper;

@Override
public CustomerViewData addCustomer(CustomerData custData) {
    Customer cr = this.mapper.customerDataToCustomer(custData);
    cr = this.custRepo.save(cr);
    return this.mapper.fromCustToCustViewData(cr);
}
}
```

Customer Service interface

```
package com.application.service;

@Component
public interface CustomerService {

CustomerViewData addCustomer(CustomerData custData);

}
```

Customer Mapper

```
package com.application.mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomerMapper {
CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CustomerMapper.class);

CustomerViewData fromCustToCustViewData(Customer entity);
}
```

Main Class

```
package com.application;

@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.application", "com.application.mapper" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.application.repository"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error -

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field mapper in com.application.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.application.mapper.CustomerMapper' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.application.mapper.CustomerMapper' in your configuration.

```
Note - Package structure is Main Class in com.appliaction,
 Mapper class in com.application.mapper, 
 CustomerService class in com.application.service,
 CustomerServiceImpl class in com.application.service.impl
```

Comment: Make sure that your code is generated properly and that it is in a package covered by the component-scanning.

Comment: You didn't register your Mapper in the spring context. Add it yo a \@Configuration class or create one with an \@Bean method

Comment: @M.Deinum @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.application"}) this is added in my main class....and Mapper class is in com.application.mapper... Pls suggest

Comment: @JEY Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You shouldn't even need the `@ComponentScan` if your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the proper package. Please include packages in your code samples here and include your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have update the post.. main class is in the base package and other packages are inside base packages..

Comment: Again, please include the package names in the classes...

Comment: @M.Deinum I have update ..pls suggest

Comment: For starters ditch the `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` those are enabled by default. Make sure that you have setup MapStruct correctly with the compiler, so that the classes are actually being generated. Finally remove the `@Component` on the `UserService` interface, it doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CustomerMapper.class);` inside CustomerMapper.class. This here seems like recursive hell to me.

You are inside `CustomerMapper.class`, just do what you want with `this.`

Outside of `CustomerMapper.class` just use autowiring to use the mapper class.

You have defined `componentModel = "spring"` so it will be bound to the spring context. Don't mix manual retrievals of the mapper with the spring context.

Probably this causes the instance not to be created and then spring throws an error.

Answer (score -1):

This is fixed, problem was the maven plugin.

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```